# Understanding "global" RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm, match, combinations

The output I expect for `"test".match(/[a-z]{0,}/g);` should contain `'', 't', 'e', 's', 't', 'te', 'es', 'st'`, etc.

However I only get `''` and `'test'` from the console. What's happening here?

Comment: You are using greedy match so it will try to match maximum possible characters. Can you try this lazy matching regex `([a-z]+?)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are looking for is all word combinations, here is a code I've worked on:

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function removeDuplicateElement(arrayName) {
    var newArray=new Array();
    label: for(var i=0; i<arrayName.length;i++){
        for(var j=0; j<newArray.length;j++) {
            if(newArray[j]==arrayName[i]) 
                continue label;
        }
        newArray[newArray.length] = arrayName[i];
    }
    return newArray;
}

var all=new Array();
var str="test";
for (;str.length>0;str=str.substring(1,str.length)) {
    for (var i = 0; i<=str.length;i++){
        var patt1=new RegExp("([a-z]{"+i+","+i+"})", "g");
        all=all.concat(str.match(patt1));
    }
}

document.write(removeDuplicateElement(all));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

For 'test', it returns ',t,e,s,te,st,tes,test,es,est'.

Answer (score 4):

Your regex matches the full text in the first pass, and an empty string in the second pass, this is why.

Unfortunately, what you want requires that the regex engine support the `\G` modifier (IIRC), which ECMA 262 regexes don't have.

Answer (score 1):

You only get `["", "test"]` because the quantifier `{0,}` will match either zero or any number of letters (just like `*`) and is greedy (just like `*`) so it matches the maximum number it can find (and zero).

Comment: The `''` match contains zero characters, which is not maximal!

Comment: @Randomblue: right; per fge's answer, on the first pass it matches zero characters, then on the second pass it matches the maximum number.

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to what a "pass" is.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create this functionality yourself you could try something like:

```
String.prototype.fullMatch = function () {
    var matches = [""]; // "" is always a match

    function do_regex(str, startAt) {
        var len = str.length,
            i,
            j,
            regex,
            all_matches = [];

        for (i = startAt; i < len; i++) {
            regex = new RegExp("[a-z]{" + (i + 1) + "}", "g");
            all_matches = str.match(regex);
            for (j = 0; j < all_matches.length; j++) {
                matches.push(all_matches[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    for (var k = 0; k < this.length; k ++) {
        do_regex(this.substring(k), k);
    }

    return matches;  
};

console.log("test".fullMatch()); // ["", "t", "e", "s", "t", "te", "st", "tes", "test", "es", "est"]
```

Comment: What about `es`, `est`, etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

Matching a string against a global regular expression will always give you the longest possible non-overlapping substrings. The first longest match is the entire string `"test"`, and then the empty string `""` remains, which is a match, too. You could achieve what you want by matching against several regular expressions with different length specifiers, like so:

```
"test".match(/[a-z]{0}/g);
"test".match(/[a-z]{1}/g);
"test".match(/[a-z]{2}/g);
"test".match(/[a-z]{3}/g);
"test".match(/[a-z]{4}/g);
```

Of course, this should be done more elegantly; you could construct those regular expressions dynamically using `new RegExp("[string]")`, for instance. Still, this would not yield `"es"`, for instance (although you could work around that again), but according to your question you don't want to get this match anyway.

Answer (score 1):

match returns a array of matches, with each starting after the end of the previous match.  If you instead use `"test".match(/[a-z]/g);` you would get `["t", "e", "s", "t"]` as a result.  "t" is matched, the next thing that matches after "t" is "e"...

In your query, the regex matches the entire string, so it emits "test", after that the empty string that follows "test" matches (since you used {0,} instead of {1,}.